# How to get a recurring function without a RangeError

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the time to display on the terminal, pretty simple. I want every console.log to be a different second. Instead of running an infinite while loop like a neanderthal, I wanted node js to wait a second before running the function. However, this doesn't seem to work as it keeps printing the same time over and over again for maybe a couple of seconds, and then I get a RangeError since I exceeded the call stack size (whatever that means). I copied this from working code in a JavaScript/HTML app I made, which works perfectly, but I'm assuming node doesn't like some of it. Ideas?

```
function addZeroes(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        var new_num = "0" + num  
    } else {
        var new_num = num
    }
    return new_num
}

function timeClock(){
    var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
    mytime = setTimeout(timeDisplay() , {}, refresh)
}
function timeDisplay() {
    //creating elements
    rightNow = new Date();
    minute = rightNow.getMinutes(); 
    hour = rightNow.getHours(); 
    seconds = rightNow.getSeconds();
    theTime = ""
    theTime += addZeroes(hour) + ":" + addZeroes(minute) + ":" + addZeroes(seconds);

    //displaying elements
    console.log(theTime)
    timeClock()
}

timeDisplay()
```

I assume the first function is irrelevant to the problem, but I don't know at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you don't want to use `setTimeout` but rather [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

Example code:

```
function addZeroes(num) {
    let new_num;
    if (num < 10) {
         new_num = "0" + num  
    } else {
         new_num = num
    }
    return new_num
}

function timeClock(){
    const refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
    let mytime = setInterval(timeDisplay, refresh)
}
function timeDisplay() {
    //creating elements
    let rightNow = new Date();
    let minute = rightNow.getMinutes(); 
    let hour = rightNow.getHours(); 
    let seconds = rightNow.getSeconds();
    let theTime = "";
    theTime += addZeroes(hour) + ":" + addZeroes(minute) + ":" + addZeroes(seconds);

    //displaying elements
    console.log(theTime);
}

timeClock();
```

If your end goal is bigger than printing to terminal, I'd recommend working with libraries like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), that have numerous helper functions rather than adding zeroes.

EDIT: You also probably want to end the execution of this function programatically. For this matter, use [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) with your variable `myTime` as a parameter.

Comment: works great! i think that using var exclusively is also part of the reason my code didn't work, gotta go back to basics lol. Have a nice day fellow programmer

Comment: Glad I could help! You could use `var` all the way, but I prefer the `let/const` syntax, it appears clearer to me and it's more recent.